# C - Structure's pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm having trouble understanding **pointers** in general I think.
I can't seem to follow the logic of this code:

```
    typedef struct StackRecord
{
    int Capacity;
    int TopOfStack;
    int* Array;
}*Stack;
```

In the following structure, ***Stack** was declared to receive addresses of **StackRecord** structure type via simply stating **Stack** due to typedef

BUT code below the return another receiver of addresss of **StackRecord** structure type. Why isn't it returning the address? But rather return same type of pointer to itself?

```
Stack CreateStack(int MaxElements)
{
    Stack S;

    if (MaxElements < MinStackSize)
    {
        printf("Error : Stack size is too small");
        return 0;
    }
    S = (Stack)malloc(sizeof(struct StackRecord));

    if (S == NULL)
    {
        printf("FatalError : Out of Space!!!");
        return 0;
    }

    S->Array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(char)* MaxElements);

    if (S->Array == NULL)
    {
        printf("FatalError : Out of Space!!!");
        return 0;
    }
    S->Capacity = MaxElements;
    MakeEmpty(S);

    return S;
}
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question and post a [MCVE]?.

Comment: Hide pointer with `typedef` is always a bad idea...

Comment: Casts of `malloc` return values, using [tag:c], are useless.

Comment: First rule to follow: **never ever** `typedef` pointers! You already notice one negative effect of this bad practice: confusion. For the rest, a good C book will provide the information you need to write C programs.

Comment: [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers) — the short answer is "No".

Comment: Don't forget to terminate messages with newlines; they may not appear if you don't.  Also, error messages should be reported on `stderr`, not `stdout`.  The standard error stream is precisely for error messages, so they're not confused with ordinary output from the program.

Comment: Even though I fully agree with what\`s written above on pointer `typedef`-ing, for the graet justice I must note that at least two of the major OS families — Windows and MacOS, respectively — do practice this: e.g., [LPSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx#LPSTR) and [CFStringRef](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1151.16/CFBase.h#CFStringRef).

Comment: @hidefromkgb, that big software producers sometimes lay an egg is no justification for anyone else to emulate the resulting examples of poor practice.  It's perhaps an *explanation*, but that's all the more reason for those poor practices to be called out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting rid of the typedef *may* make things a little clearer, believe it or not:

```
struct StackRecord
{
    int Capacity;
    int TopOfStack;
    int* Array;
};

/**
 * Return a pointer to a new, dynamically allocated instance
 * of struct StackRecord
 */
struct StackRecord *CreateStack(int MaxElements) 
{
    struct StackRecord *S;

    if (MaxElements < MinStackSize)
    {
        printf("Error : Stack size is too small");
        return 0;
    }
    S = malloc(sizeof *S); // no need for cast, sizeof *S is same as sizeof (struct StackRecord)

    if (S == NULL)
    {
        printf("FatalError : Out of Space!!!");
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * Allocate the memory for the Array member of
     * the new stack record instance.
     */
    S->Array = malloc( sizeof *S->Array * MaxElements );

    if (S->Array == NULL)
    {
        printf("FatalError : Out of Space!!!");
        return 0;
    }
    S->Capacity = MaxElements;
    MakeEmpty(S);

    return S;
}
```

In the code you posted, `Stack` is basically a synonym for `struct StackRecord *`.  The function creates a new instance of `struct StackRecord` using `malloc`, initializes the contents of that record, and returns a pointer to that new instance.

A note on the `malloc` calls - in C, you do not need to cast the result of `malloc`, and doing so is generally considered bad practice<sup>1</sup>. Also, the operand to `sizeof` doesn't have to be a type name - it can be an expression *of* the type you want to allocate.  IOW, given a declaration like

```
T *p;
```

both `sizeof (T)` and `sizeof *p` do the same thing - the *expression* `*p` has type `T`.  So the general form of a malloc call can be written as

```
T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * N );
```

or

```
T *p;
...
p = malloc( sizeof *p * N );
```

That's simpler to write and easier to maintain than

```
p = (T *) malloc( sizeof (T) * N );
```

<rant>

Hiding the pointer-ness of a type behind a typedef is bad juju, *especially* when the user of that type *has to be aware* that he or she is dealing with a pointer type.  Assigning the result of `malloc` to `S` means that `S` *must* be a pointer type.  Using the `->` to access members of `S` means that `S` *must* be a pointer to a `struct` or `union` type.  Since you *have* to be aware that `S` is a pointer, it makes no sense to hide that pointerness behind the typedef.  Similarly, if the user has to be aware of the `struct`-ness of the type, you shouldn't hide that `struct`-ness behind a typedef either.

Abstraction is a powerful tool, but partial (leaky) abstractions like the original code just make life more confusing for everyone (as you have discovered for yourself).

</rant>

---

1. This is *not* true for C++, because C++ doesn't allow implicit conversions between `void *` and other pointer types the way C does.  But, if you're writing C++, you shouldn't be using `malloc` anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I am revising all my code with your advice. It indeed did made it clearer for me to understand once I took out typedef from the code itself.

Comment: Great answer. I would, however, suggest changing `sizeof *p * N`, etc. to `N * sizeof *p`, which looks (to me) a little more like a multiplication and is less likely to raise questions about the precedence of the `sizeof` operator. Parenthesizing the `sizeof` expression, like `(sizeof *p) * N`, is another good option.

Answer (score 2):

In the typedef, the type identifier `Stack` is a pointer to a struct. The function prototype for `CreateStack()` specifies a return value of type `Stack`, which is a pointer to a `StackRecord` struct. `S` is declared to be of type `Stack` in the function body, so the function does return a pointer to a `StackRecord` struct.

Comment: Did you really understand what OP is asking for? Awesome! :)

Comment: Yes, this is my exact confusion. Why is it returning pointer to function `CreateStack()` which is specified as a return type of a pointer to struct rather than address of the memory? since return value of type is Stack, which is a pointer, shouldn't it only be able to receive address?

Comment: @Sysnaptic, what is this distinction you're drawing between a "pointer to a StackRecord struct" and the "address of the memory"?  A pointer *is* an address, or at least the equivalent of one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger `Stack` is a pointer to `StackRecord` which means pointer must contain another address to which it is pointing to. But this case, a return value of `CreateStack()`, does not provide the specific address it points to... or does it...?

Comment: Oh my gosh. I am so sorry. You are absolutely right! Since return type is a pointer of `StackRecord` it must return pointer of `StackRecord`. Thank you for confirming the code!

Answer (score 1):

In comments on @DavidBowling's answer you express this apparent misconception:

> `Stack` is a pointer to `StackRecord` which means pointer must contain another address to which it is pointing to.

The typedef declares the identifier `Stack` to be an alias for the type `struct StackRecord *`.  That would perhaps be clearer if it were rewritten in this wholly equivalent form:

```
struct StackRecord
{
    int Capacity;
    int TopOfStack;
    int* Array;
};

typedef struct StackRecord *Stack;
```

No object of type `struct StackRecord` is declared, only that type itself and type `Stack`.

When function `CreateStack()` allocates memory sufficient for a `struct StackRecord` ...

```
malloc(sizeof(struct StackRecord));
```

... it is perfectly reasonable to convert the resulting pointer to type `struct StackRecord *`.  Indeed, *type* `Stack` is exactly the same type as `struct StackRecord *`, so that's precisely what the code in fact does.  The converted pointer still points to the same memory, and when that pointer is returned, the return value also points to the same memory.